# URL to access to Calendar HTML

Tags: zimbra

I'm trying to embed the html code of zimbra calendar inside one page, but I'm having trouble figuring out the URL to use. In the example given to me, if you visit in your browser:

```
https://zcs.domain.com/service/home/someuser@domain.com/SomeEvents.html?view=month
```

you get a zimbra page only with the calendar (no ribbon, no zimlets, just the calendar).

I've tried to make the same with my user, but I don't know how to build the URL, so jetty gives me an 404 error.

Which URL should I visit to get my calendar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't build the URL yourself--instead:

1. Login to your Zimbra interface.
2. Find the calendar you want to share.
3. Right-click, select "Share Calendar"
4. Select "Public"
5. Copy the HTML link from the bottom of the window

Making a public viewer share will allow you to view the HTML without logging in.
Make sure you click "OK" to create the public share before you visit the link.